# What does it mean that skewed join does not address uneven data?

Tags: join, hadoop, apache-pig

From Pig's Skewed Join [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/perf.html#skewed-joins):

> Skewed join does not address (balance) uneven data distribution across
>   reducers. However, in most cases, skewed join ensures that the join
>   will finish (however slowly) rather than fail.

Could someone explain what this means? Isn't the whole point of skewed join to actually handle such skewed data and spread it correctly across reducers?

Comment: This doc has more detailed information about it: https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigSkewedJoinSpec. I agree the sentence is odd -- My reading of the docs is the same as yours. Possibly it is referring to the fact that a key will be split across as few reducers as possible, so you'll still have one or a few reducers at capacity and others finishing quickly.